# SWIG & C#: rewrite void returning methods to return the class instance itself

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper, swig

I'm trying create a C# wrapper for C++ code that rewrites all void-returning methods to return a reference to the class instance itself to allow chained method invocation with the C#-side API.

However, this seems to be a non-trivial thing; csout typemap allows for rewriting the body of void-returning methods, but not the function signature. This doesn't work:

```
%typemap(csout, excode=SWIGEXCODE) void {
    $imcall;$excode
    return this;
}
```

On the other hand, cstype typemap allows for rewriting the type void, but when trying to rewrite that, $csclassname refers to the void type itself (producing SWIGTYPE_void), not to the class containing the method that returns a void type:

```
%typemap(cstype, out="$csclassname") void "void"
```

I know SWIG isn't intended for this type of transformation, but it seems to be so close. It'd be quite irritating to stack another build tool to do the one more transformation. Does SWIG stretch to provide this?

EDIT: It just occured me that I can change the C++ return types to return pointer to the class itself. (I'm the author of the C++ lib and I'm developing further it at the moment.) Then using a rule like this, I can get what I wanted:

```
%typemap(csout, excode=SWIGEXCODE) SWIGTYPE * {
    $imcall;$excode
    return this;
}
```

The only downside is now that SWIGTYPE * refers to ANY kind of pointer. I'd like to make it to match only pointers of the type of the class itself. Isn't there any way to have more expressive type matching? Or $special_variables that have the name of the containing class?